# Is there a library for editing MP4 Metadata with Scala or Java?

Tags: java, scala, ffmpeg, id3

I've been using `ffmpeg` for the task by simply calling it from Scala. However, it's remarkably overkill to do so, as `ffmpeg` *requires* you to have an output file. So I'm creating entire copies of video files *just* so I can modify the ID3 tags. It's time, and CPU taxing to say the least.

Obviously, they *can* be editing in place (for instance, by manually changing the tags in the property dialog in windows). Surely there's a way to do the same thing programatically?

Comment: Can those people that vote "off-topic" explain why this is the case? I am rather annoyed that every time someone asks for a library on SO, people are clicking on "close". Asking for libraries is totally on topic IMO.

Comment: The reason "which library?" questions are considered off topic is that SO is looking for questions that have a reasonable chance of having an answer that can be accepted. With library recommendations that chances are that there are two or more competing libraries which are both equally valid. Personally I find that sort of question useful too but I can see why they don't fit well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) library supports MP4 metadata. It can even modify the data and has a fairly user friendly API.

[This](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) library might also prove helpful for non-ID3 metadata.

Comment: Jaudiotagger does not support MP4 video. The OP does specify editing video files, not just MP4 audio containers.